# Jquery: Mapping XML Nodes to HTML ID elements

Tags: jquery, xml, data-mapping

never easy to encapsulate what to say in the title... but here we go...

I realise I am probably seeing straight past the obvious, and possibly built in function of JQuery.

What I am trying to do is:

1. Have an XML file (locally or via server) contain nodes which happen to have their 
   node names i.e.  as ID names of say a textbox in HTML
   i.e.
2. I want to then via the JQuery AJAX call, parse the XML and map the values of the nodes
   to the value of the HTML ID elements of the same node name...

I realise straight away there are a) probably plugins, b) maybe better concepts, but I only need to map to basic HTML elements.. and in fact I could technically have some more advanced features to populate say combo boxes, radio buttons etc....

Just any ideas of a path to follow? or if there is a simple JQuery Plugin to do this?

P.S:  I wasn't into templates as such, because even though I realise the power of say jTemplates, I don't really need anything as complex/flexible as that...

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Do you only want to find the elements with the ids? Or do you have content that you want to insert into them? Could you provide an example of what the xml file could look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.get ('/path/to/xml', function (data)
{
    $(data).children ().each (function ()
    {
        $('#' + this.nodeName).val ($(this).text());
    });
})
```

Assumes only 1 level of nesting in the XML.

Answer (score 3):

this should get you started on xml parsing..

```
var xml = '<root><text1>i am in text1</text1><text2>i am in text2</text2></root>';
$(xml)
      .children()
      .each(
            function(){
                       alert(this.nodeName + ':' + $(this).text());
                      }
           );
```

nodeName is the tag name in xml which you will use as id for the html ..
the jquery text method will return the value of the xml node .. (text only)

to load the xml file use

```
$.get( 
      '/path/to/filename.xml', 
      function(){ 
                 /*runs on success, do the parsing here*/
                },
      'xml'
     );
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually great input, thanks guys for helping.. it has got me going.

Again, I realise there are templating engines out there, but my next step is to build a little more complexity to be able to say populate a combo box, radio button etc.. just the basics of HTML.. because I am using the [DHTMLX components](http://www.dhtmlx.com) to do any fancy things.. mainly as they seem to have the easiest to understand javascript widgets I have found.. I know ExtJS are catching up with better docco, easier API's etc..

So in Summary, I will have:

1. Fields in a database named the same throughout my system.. so if a database field
   is called firstname, then the HTML element will be called firstname
2. In my XML that I create from the database, I will add attributes like 'Element Type'
   which will be say text, radio, combo or whatever, so I know how to populate the values.
3. Then the javascript/JQuery can do what it needs to display the data..

The main reason for all of this is that my partner can just design the page/layout as pure HTML, not worry about XSLT/Templates... and the data simple is populated...

I am sure there must be some "engine/plugin" out there.. but for now I will work on it...

Thanks again...

Answer (score 0):

```
$(xml).find('foo').each( function() {
  alert (this.text());
});
```